# Python 3.4.1 - putting variables into input

Tags: python, variables, input

This is my code:

```
import random
x = random.randint(2,10)
y = random.randint(2,10)
answer = int(input("How much is x * y?"))
```

I have to use variables `x, y` in my input, so the user will see this when they run the program (the program is obviously not completed, I just need help with this):

```
How much is 3 * 5?
```

But I have no idea how to put those variables inside of the input.. please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `format`:

```
import random
x = random.randint(2, 10)
y = random.randint(2, 10)
answer = int(input("How much is {} * {}?".format(x, y)))
```

Try not to use the `%` operator. `format` is preferred over this, especially since python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Its a matter of [simple string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting):

```
"How much is %d * %d?" % (x, y)
```

Comment: should use .format rather than the older % operator